# Error: "is not an attribute class" when using ConfigurationElementType attribute

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, enterprise-library

I'm trying to create a custom exception handler for the exception handling block of enterprise library 5.0.  As far as I understand I need to start the class off with the attribute 
"[ConfigurationElementType(typeof(CustomHandlerData))]". But I get an error stating the ConfigurationElementType is not an attribute class.

Does anyone know what might be going on?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try adding the keyword Attribute after ConfigurationElementType.  It is not required, but this may get you to a more helpful error message... my guess would be that you are missing references... that's always the problem with EntLib.

Comment: Wow, thanks so much.  This indeed fixed the problem.  Strange how all the resources out there (including msdn) use ConfigurationElementType rather than ConfigurationElementTypeAttribute.

Answer (score 5):

Be sure to add the reference to the System.ComponentModel.Compostion or Sytem.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations to your project under Project-Add References .Net tab.

Then you should be able to include 'using System.ComponentModel;' in your project to get your attributes working properly.

Comment: adding System.ComponentModel.Compostion to references worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Adding Enterprise Library Shared Library assembly to the references of the project worked for me. Then, you can add the using `Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common.Configuration;`